# How can I help my 2 Border Collie puppies (3 years old) learn to play with my older toy-breed dog (12 years old)?

Tags: dogs, training

I have two 3-year-old puppies that I got when they were just a couple of weeks old. I also have a 12-year-old Pomeranian-Chihuahua male whom I've had for a lot longer, and who seems to have been getting along with the puppies since I first brought them home. In fact, when the puppies play with each other, the Pom-Chi tries to join in. However, the puppies are big relative to him and play a little too rough for his liking. What can I do to help my Pom-Chi feel more comfortable playing with them?

Comment: How does the small one show that he does not like the roughness?